# CakePHP Email signup form in home page

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I need my signup form with email input to work wherever I want on the site.
I have an EmailsController that has add() and will add an email when I am on the add page.

How do I get the layout for Emails/Add.ctp to be injected into my home page and wherever I like while keeping the functionality and giving feedback to a user?

```
<div>
<?= $this->Element('upone_scriptimports'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->control('email'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class'=>'btn btn-default text-right right']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use elements, see [CookBook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements)

Put your code in here: `src/Template/Element/Emails/add.ctp`, you use your element like this `echo $this->element('Emails/add');`

> Also add an action attribute to your form, specifying the controller
>   and action that will process the data.

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, [
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'publish']
]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('email'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), [
    'class' => 'btn btn-default text-right right'
]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**See** [Setting a URL for the Form](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#setting-a-url-for-the-form)

Comment: that puts it into the layout, but it doesn't actually sign up, ive edited with current code

Comment: I did not understand you.

Comment: The layout goes in. But when I hit submit, nothing happens

Comment: If you include this element in a different route from EmailsController, you must to provide an action on Form->create().

Comment: Route? So if I connect the home page with the signup function it'll work?

Comment: I updated the answer, add an action to your form. Remember that, if this form is available to unlogged users, the action must be allowed for them.

Comment: so: <rest of form>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['controller'=>'Emails', 'action'=>'add'], ['class'=>'btn btn-default text-right right']) ?> will do it. Is a route->conenct (emails controller, action needed).  I want to be able to hit submit, and it perform the same action as it would if i was on the /Emails/add page.

Comment: You put the controller and action keys on the wrong element, I have updated the answer again with an example.